# What is the keybinding command name for Code Search in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I used to use Control-Q to go to a file that I wanted to open. I updated my visual studio today and now when I do control-Q it does a "feature search" rather than the previous behavior. When I click on the search icon at the top it shows the following: [image: new search]

When I look for the code search keybinding in the keybindings editor, there exists only the following:
[image: keybindings]

is there a specific name for the code search feature?

I looked through all the microsoft keybinding docs and only quicklaunch is available, which gives me the visual studio feature search.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is exactly that you want? Because the title question is what the command name is for Code Search, but in the actual question context, it is the one that you found in the image (Window.QuickLaunch) which I confirm by testing on my own installation. So the answer to the title, is in the image from the context. So I am unsure what it is that you need. If you want more info about the feature itself, here is the post from when MS launched it back in 2022: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/introducing-a-new-way-to-search-your-code-and-visual-studio-features/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command name for the "Code Search" is `Edit.GoToAll`.